# How to present this particular integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int\frac{x^2+3x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}dx
$$
How to present this integral?

Comment: Try a substitution which completes the square in the radicand.  Then a trigonometric substitution to resolve the radical.

Comment: Why do you call this a "particle" integration? Also, it is best on this site to learn how to enter the equation rather than linking to a picture.

Comment: we have $$x^2+6x+10=(x+3)^2+1$$

Comment: have you tried mathematica? it might be useful to specify your problem

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the substitution $\; x+3=\sinh t,\enspace \mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\cosh t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{x^2+3x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{x^2+3x}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2+1}}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=x+3$ and $\text{d}u=\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{(u-3)^2+3(u-3)}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan(s)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(s)\text{d}s$.

Then $\sqrt{u^2+1}=\sqrt{\tan^2(s)+1}=\sec(s)$ and $s=\arctan(u)$:

---

$$\int\left(\left(\tan(s)-3\right)^2+3\left(\tan(s)-3\right)\right)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\int\tan^2(s)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s-3\int\tan(s)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s=$$

---

Use $\tan^2(s)=\sec^2(s)-1$:

---

$$\int\sec^3(s)\space\text{d}s-\int\sec(s)\space\text{d}s-3\int\tan(s)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s=$$

---

Now, use the reduction formula:

$$\int\sec^m(s)\space\text{d}s=\frac{\sin(s)\sec^{m-1}(s)}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int\sec^{m-2}(s)\space\text{d}s$$

And for $\int\tan(s)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s$, substitute $q=\sec(s)$ and $\text{d}q=\tan(s)\text{d}s$:

---

$$\int\sec^3(s)\space\text{d}s-\int\sec(s)\space\text{d}s-3\int1\space\text{d}q=$$
$$\int\sec^3(s)\space\text{d}s-\int\sec(s)\space\text{d}s-3q=$$

---

Use:

$$\int\sec(s)\space\text{d}s=\ln\left|\sec(s)+\tan(s)\right|+\text{C}$$

---

$$\int\sec^3(s)\space\text{d}s-\ln\left|\sec(s)+\tan(s)\right|-3\sec(s)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With the *Euler sub*$\ds{\ldots\root{x^{2} + 6x + 10} - x \equiv t\ \imp\
x = -\,\half\,{t^{2} - 10 \over t - 3}}$ the integral is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\int{x^{2} + 3x \over \root{x^{2} + 6x + 10}}\,\dd x & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int{\pars{t^{2} - 10}\pars{t - 2 }\pars{t - 4} \over
\pars{t - 3}^{3}}\,\dd t
\end{align}
which can be integrated by partial fraction expansion.

---

For instance,
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{t^{2} - 10} & \ds{=} & \ds{\pars{t - 3}^{2} + 6\pars{t - 3} - 1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\pars{t - 2}\pars{t - 4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\pars{t - 3}^{2} - 1} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
such that
\begin{align}
\pars{t^{2} - 10}\pars{t - 2 }\pars{t - 4} =
\pars{t - 3}^{4} + 6\pars{t - 3}^{3} - 2\pars{t - 3}^{2} - 6\pars{t - 3} + 1
\end{align}